# keyboard not appearing when clicking iOS input text field/view no matter where I put them

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

Hi all for some reason in my iOS project on the latest Xcode6 the keyboard is refusing to appear anymore when I click inside a input textfield or textview.

I did have one of my fields dismissing the keyboard via

```
.h
IBOutlet UITextField *textField; {
}

- (IBAction)dismissKeyboard:(id)sender;

.m
- (IBAction)dismissKeyboard:(id)sender {
[textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

but even when I delete this code, even tried deleting the view controller files & storyboard and have tried dragging the input textfield/view onto my other view controllers/views and still it refuses to appear no matter where I put it!

Also tried doing a clean, restarting Xcode and the Mac itself.

At the moment I don't even have any custom code in my controller file .m or h.

Apart from restarting the project I'm not sure how I get this default behaviour of the keyboard appearing when clicking inside an input back!

The only thing I have been doing in my other storyboard view controllers is experimenting with constraints/autolayout.

Scratching my head, apart from starting a new project file I'm not sure what to do, any help would be great

Comment: have you looked at the at the details in the attribute inspectorof the interface builder? there are various keyboard setting, maybe you accidentally deactivated it.

Comment: I met the same problem before, when you run you app with real device, it works.

Comment: wow guys what a nightmare lost an hour on this the answer is in iOS Simulator, click on "Hardware", then go to Keyboard and uncheck the option "Connect Hardware Keyboard". I didn't even turn this thing on, some how it checked itself, must have accidentally press the keyboard short cut or accidentally enabled it getting out of a menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boss, Go to Simulator-> select Hardware -> go to keyboard -> and then do toggle keyboard.It works.Cheers

Comment: if answer is correct accept as correct answer and upvote it.thank u.